# how to select node using attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

Hi given that i have this XML

```
        <Workflow>
            <WorkflowDefinitionCode>WFDC</WorkflowDefinitionCode>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="Status" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="Products" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="Description" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="QuoteID" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="LogicalID" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="TotalAmount" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="DiscountRequest" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="AssignedTo" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="ItemName" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="CustomerName" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="Approval" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <NameValue name="QuoteString" type="StringType" />
            </Property>
        </Workflow>
```

how would i select the node NameValue using its attribute value like name='Status'

i tried using `/Workflow/Property/NameValue[@name='Products']`

but its always selecting the first NameValue node regardless of the attribute value that i put on the Xpath in this example its "Products"

do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your XPath should've returned `<NameValue name="Products" type="StringType" />` : http://xpatheval.apphb.com/8nU_MWU10

Comment: i want to put a value on that node to be precise

Comment: Your `XPath` seem to work as expected. Can your clarify your issue: what is desired/current output?